# What are the Google Drive Site Publishing limitations and loading speed?

Tags: google-drive-api

- How many requests are allowed?
- How much bandwidth is allowed?
- How does the loading speed compare with Amazon's S3 / CloudFront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests:
There's a Drive API daily quota of 500,000 requests/day ("courtesy limit") which you can find from your API dashboard (https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Bandwidth:
Google Apps for Business and Education have published bandwidth limits although I don't know if these are the same as for the Drive API:

```
Download: 750 MB/hr and 1250 MB/day
Upload: 300 MB/hr and 500 MB/day
```

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1071518

Compared to Amazon's S3 / CloudFront? I'm not convinced that it's a like for like comparison. Drive would have to be compared to DropBox, Box.com, SkyDrive, iCloud and the rest.

> Google Cloud Storage enables application developers to store their
>   data on Google’s infrastructure with very high reliability,
>   performance and availability. If you’re looking to store personal data
>   in the cloud, consider using Google Drive instead. Or, if you are are
>   an app developer who wants to integrate with Google Drive, you can do
>   so using the Google Drive SDK.
>   https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started